# Not able to get Arquillian running with my Spring framework

Tags: spring, maven, jpa, cdi, jboss-arquillian

I face following error trying to run my basic test case with spring + JPA  + JSF + Primefaces project

Could you please help?

```
16:52:51,394 INFO  [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.cdi.JpaRepositoryExtension] (MSC service thread 1-11) Activating CDI extension for Spring Data JPA repositories.
    ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."787b2f47-cedc-492a-bb96-e58a02b72772.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."787b2f47-cedc-492a-bb96-e58a02b72772.war".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "787b2f47-cedc-492a-bb96-e58a02b72772.war"
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [wildfly-server-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer: Provider org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer not found
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:239) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:185) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:372) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.deploy(ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.java:112)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [wildfly-server-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
        ... 5 more

    ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "787b2f47-cedc-492a-bb96-e58a02b72772.war")]) - failure description: {
        "JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"787b2f47-cedc-492a-bb96-e58a02b72772.war\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"787b2f47-cedc-492a-bb96-e58a02b72772.war\".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"787b2f47-cedc-492a-bb96-e58a02b72772.war\"
        Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer: Provider org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer not found"},
        "JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"787b2f47-cedc-492a-bb96-e58a02b72772.war\".weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"787b2f47-cedc-492a-bb96-e58a02b72772.war\".beanmanager]"]
    }
    ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "787b2f47-cedc-492a-bb96-e58a02b72772.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
    {
        "JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"787b2f47-cedc-492a-bb96-e58a02b72772.war\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"787b2f47-cedc-492a-bb96-e58a02b72772.war\".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"787b2f47-cedc-492a-bb96-e58a02b72772.war\"
        Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer: Provider org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer not found"},
        "JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"787b2f47-cedc-492a-bb96-e58a02b72772.war\".weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"787b2f47-cedc-492a-bb96-e58a02b72772.war\".beanmanager]"]
    }
    INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] JBAS010409: Unbound data source [java:/jdbc/cdis-db]
    INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] JBAS015877: Stopped deployment 787b2f47-cedc-492a-bb96-e58a02b72772.war (runtime-name: 787b2f47-cedc-492a-bb96-e58a02b72772.war) in 370ms
    INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] JBAS014774: Service status report
    JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
          service jboss.deployment.unit."787b2f47-cedc-492a-bb96-e58a02b72772.war".beanmanager (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."787b2f47-cedc-492a-bb96-e58a02b72772.war".weld.weldClassIntrospector] 
    JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."787b2f47-cedc-492a-bb96-e58a02b72772.war".INSTALL
```

My deployment is as follows and datasource is defined well. pom-test.xml contains the dependencies required for my project including sprint-test, spring-core and sprint-data-jpa etc.

```
@Deployment
public static Archive<?> createTestArchive() {
    Archive jar = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class)
            .addClasses(Greeter.class, PhraseBuilder.class)
            .addAsLibraries(
                    Maven.resolver().loadPomFromClassLoaderResource("META-INF/pom-test.xml")
                            .importRuntimeDependencies().resolve().withTransitivity().asFile())
            .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml")
            .addAsWebInfResource("META-INF/jboss-ds.xml")
            // Deploy our test datasource
            ;
    System.out.println(jar.toString(true));
    return jar;

}
```

Comment: Seems that `spring-web` is not within the deployment. See http://arquillian.org/guides/getting_started_rinse_and_repeat/#export_the_deployment and check for the contents of your deployment.

Comment: I tried that. But i think that one is already added when i add sprint-web-security. And i hit the same error even if i add that dependency explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working with the help of my colleague.
There were a couple of things i had to change

1. I had to use wildfly-arquillian-container-managed instead of embedded

dependency
groupId:org.wildfly
artifactId:wildfly-arquillian-container-managed
version:8.2.1.Final

2. I was not creating the war file with right WEB-INF config files

   ```
   File[] files = Maven.resolver().loadPomFromFile("pom.xml")
           .importRuntimeDependencies().resolve().withTransitivity().asFile();

   WebArchive war = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "test-cdisonline.war")
           .addAsLibraries(files)

           // need to filter out non container tests
           .addPackages(true, Filters.include(".*ContainerTest.*"), "au.com.xxx.xxx")
           .addPackages(true, Filters.exclude(".*Test.*|.*ModelJPAConfig.*|.*ApplicationConfig.*"), "au.com.ibm.cdis")

           // need to added arquillian test to war
           .addPackages(true, "au.com.xxx.arquillian")

           // add as a resource forces persistence.xml into the WEB-INF/classess folder which is visible to classloader when
           // searching
           .addAsResource(new File(META_INF,"persistence.xml"),"META-INF/persistence.xml")


           .addAsResource(new File("src/test/resources/" + CDIS_ROOT, "pipeline-small.xlsx"), CDIS_ROOT + "/pipeline-small.xlsx")
           //WEB-INF
           // datasource definitions
           .addAsWebInfResource("wildfly-ds.xml")
           .addAsWebInfResource(new File(WEB_INF,"beans.xml"), "beans.xml")

           // this version of the web.xml remove resource refs as I haven't worked out how to define them dynamically during tests
           .addAsWebInfResource("test-web.xml", "web.xml")

            .addAsLibraries(new File(WEBAPP_LIB, "rio-theme-1.1.jar"))

           .addAsWebInfResource(new File(WEB_INF,"faces-config.xml"), "faces-config.xml")
           ;                                                         

   for (File f : new File(WEBAPP_SRC).listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
       @Override
       public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
           return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".xhtml");
       }
   })) {
       war.addAsWebResource(f);
   }

   logger.info(war.toString(true));

   return war;
   ```

Comment: WEB_INF = "src/main/webapp/WEB-INF"; 

META_INF = "src/main/resources/META-INF";

WEBAPP_SRC = "src/main/webapp";

WEBAPP_LIB = "src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib";